# Chrome Google Now typed input

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

Google Now has been included into Chrome on the desktop now (at least in Windows), but is there a way I can do Google Now kinds of things without speaking, and typing instead?

Like a way I could type "Ok google will it rain today" or "ok google remind me to do this at 5pm"?

Refrence: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3542118?hl=en

Comment: Just remove the "ok google" part and type your request into the omnibox.  "Ok Google" is just a keyword for phones to use to know to start voice recognition.  After that, whatever you say is just a Google search query.

Comment: I had tried that and it failed... i tried again now and it worked though. Maybe it doesn't handle all the same queries. weird. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I've found that not everything works.